# How to find a file from root with spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I have spacemacs and when I press `SPC f f` it starts of in the current directory. Problem is the file I need is in `/etc` so I first have to delete the current path by pressing backspace numerous times before I can start typing my path. Is there a way to not have a default path pre-written when pressing `SPC f f` ?

Comment: FWIW, I think you can use Ctrl-H to delete whole directories at once.

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla Emacs, typing `/` will reset the path to the root of the file system (or typing "C:/" in Windows). This behavior should be the same in Spacemacs.

So when it prompts you to find a file in the current directory (e.g. `/home/unimor/Documents`), merely type `/` and Emacs will start looking from the root.

Comment: but it doesn't, is it a bug